# IBAction func to open widget directly from my app

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, widgetkit

My question is very simple
I have a button and when I click should open a widget that I have created.

The widget is working when I open it from the normal screen.

But when I try with action is not working

Could someone give me an example code?

Thanks

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far (your existing code) and explain what's "not working" in it so we can help you based on that.

Comment: I think i fixed because I read from web that is not possible to add with a button